# How to increase font size in tab 7.0 when using ActionbarSherlock tabs?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

The text inside the tabs appears very small in tablets 7.0, when using ActionbarSherlock. 
I tried all the below solutions in the styles.xml but no effect at all. The tabs stays the same:

```
 <style name="Theme.MyApp.Default" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
   <item name="actionBarSize">48dip</item>
   <item name="android:actionBarSize">48dip</item> 
   <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyApp.SherlockActionBarStyle</item>
   <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyApp.SherlockActionBarStyle</item>
 </style>

 <style name="MyApp.SherlockActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
   <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyApp.ActionBar.TextAppearance</item>
 </style>

 <style name="MyApp.ActionBar.TextAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
   <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Styled.TabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Styled.TabText</item>
</style>

<style name="Styled.TabText" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```